# Проблема при сборке архива в xcode: undefined symbol: '_OBJC_CLASS _ $ _ SKOverlay'

Tags: unity3d, ios, xcode, admob

Всем привет! У меня есть игра, разработанная на Unity. В этой игре есть SDK GoogleMobileADS. Я пытаюсь создать архив в xcode. Добавил все нужные xcframework, а именно: GoogleMobileAds.xcframework, GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework, GoogleUtilities.xcframework, nanopb.xcframework, PromisesObjCxcframework UserMessagingPlatform.xcframework. В "Other Linker Flags" добавил "-ObjC". Также ещё добавлял другие framework в "Link Binary With Libraries"
[image: скрин всех framework 1]

[image: скрин всех framework 2]

[image: other linker flags]

После всех этих шагов я выполняю очистку проекта (Clean Build Folder) и начинаю архивировать проект для отправки в AppStore. Но в конце сборки у меня вылетают следующие ошибки:

**Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_SKOverlay**

**Undefined symbol: _SKStoreProductParameterAdNetworkSourceAppStoreIdentifier**

**Undefined symbol: _SKStoreProductParameterAdNetworkVersion**

**Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_SKOverlayAppConfiguration**

**Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_WKContentWorld**

[image: ошибки]

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Как можно исправить эти ошибки?

Comment: попробуйте еще добавить StoreKit

Comment: я уже его добавил (второй скрин, второй снизу) или имеется ввиду добавить его в каком-то другом месте? :)

Comment: даже сейчас заметил, что у меня добавлено два StoreKit... может быть из-за этого проблема, чуть позже тогда отпишусь